# if inside location nginx directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to make simple proxy_pass depending on the header value in request, but Nginx was failed to start with error: *'"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/common/nginx.conf'*.

According to the documentation "proxy_pass" can be use in context "location, if in location, limit_except" (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Could please someone explain, whan i did wrong?

My nginx config

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  _;
        
        location /api {
          if ($http_dest_api = "dev") {  
            proxy_pass 'http://dev-app/';
          }
          if ($http_dest_api = "qa") {  
            proxy_pass 'http://qa-app/';
          }
        }     
    }
```